# WebGL project building doesnt do anything

Tags: unity-webgl

I have a problem with my project's `WebGL` building.
For some reason every time I try to build it inside an empty folder that I creted for this purpose it ends up empty.
I would really appreciate any help because I cant find a solution.

Comment: Without seeing any code here, it's difficult to identify the problem. Is the project's source code available online?

Comment: [This forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/when-building-for-webgl-the-output-folder-is-empty.437600/) might be relevant, depending on which version of Unity you are using. If you are using an older version, this might be a bug that was fixed in a newer version.

Comment: I am trying to uptade but after I downloded unity hub and chooce the version i want nothing happens

Comment: hello guys I managed to uptade unity but now i have a new problem: in order to  build i need to choose a folder for it so i created a regular one but everytime i complet the build the folder dissaper and i cant find it on the pc.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have problem with showing an example since what I am tring to build is an application and i dont want to spam all the codes here.